# Google Maps API: Get Data from Array

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

i want to get data from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json/`

If it is simple json:

```
   {
     origin: "Hoboken NJ",
     destination: "Carroll Gardens, Brooklyn",
   }
```

I can change the URL to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json/?origin=Hoboken NJ&destination: Carroll Gardens, Brooklyn`.

But when the json has an array I don't know how to change the URL:

```
{
  origin: "Hoboken NJ",
  destination: "Carroll Gardens, Brooklyn",
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
  transitOptions: {
    departureTime: new Date(1337675679473),
    modes: [google.maps.TransitMode.BUS],
    routingPreference: google.maps.TransitRoutePreference.FEWER_TRANSFERS
  }}
```

Comment: Use code tags please.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your json array such as

```
parameters=JSON.parse({origin: "Hoboken NJ",destination: "Carroll Gardens, Brooklyn"});
```

then request URL can be set as:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+parameters.origin +"&destination="+parameters.destination
```

Comment: Help me with Json ,Thanks very much{
  origin: "Hoboken NJ",
  destination: "Carroll Gardens, Brooklyn",
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
  transitOptions: {
    departureTime: new Date(1337675679473),
    modes: [google.maps.TransitMode.BUS],
    routingPreference: google.maps.TransitRoutePreference.FEWER_TRANSFERS
  }